# rails 4 can only call javascript once from link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have a rails app with a list of items that I wnat to delete using javascript and hide the row.

What I experience is that if I click one link, the item deletes and the row dissapears. If I click another, the controller is not called, the pages is just refreshed through javascript.

show.html.erb

```
link_to image_tag("bin-20.png", :border => 0), '#', :title => 'Remove this item',
            data:{ deleteitem: item.id }

item.js.coffee
$ ->
    $("a[data-deleteitem]").click -> 
        urllink = "/itemisations/" + $(this).data("deleteitem") 
        divclass = ".item-" + $(this).data("deleteitem")
        $.ajax
        type: "POST"
        url: urllink
        dataType: "json"
        data:
          _method: "delete"
      $(divclass).toggle()
      alert("Item has been removed from your list")
```

If I click one link and then another. the output I get in the console is:

```
POST http://local-dev.com:3000/itemisations/636 200 OK 1.6s       jquery.js?body=1 (line 9632)
GET http://local-dev.com:3000/items/60# 200 OK 7.88s    turboli...?body=1 (line 59)
GET http://local-dev.com:3000/items/60# 200 OK 8.31s
```

So I can see that on the first click the sytem runs the delete call on the controller and then shows the view. However, on the second click the call to the controller is not run ...

Oh, and the reason I am running a link to a coffee script rather than  a link_to remote directly to controller is I wanted to be able to call toggle as part of the routine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it looks as though I fell foul of turbolink here. To get around the issue I changed my script to the following

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
    $("a[data-deleteitem]").click -> 
        urllink = "/itemisations/" + $(this).data("deleteitem") 
        divclass = ".item-" + $(this).data("deleteitem")
        $.ajax
        type: "POST"
        url: urllink
        dataType: "json"
        data:
          _method: "delete"
      $(divclass).toggle()
      alert("Item has been removed from your list")
```